# Extjs hide alpha bar and text in colorfield

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using [this](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/source/Selector.html#Ext-ux-colorpick-Selector) to pick colors from a colorfield selector. However I don't want the alpha bar to be usable and viewable. How do I hide this from my overview? It seems to be a simple question but I really don't know the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you override that class, or extend it into your own component and change the constructor to the following:

```
constructor: function (config) {
    var me             = this,
        childViewModel = Ext.Factory.viewModel('colorpick-selectormodel');

    // Since this component needs to present its value as a thing to which users can
    // bind, we create an internal VM for our purposes.
    me.childViewModel = childViewModel;
    me.items = [
        me.getMapAndHexRGBFields(childViewModel),
        me.getSliderAndHField(childViewModel),
        me.getSliderAndSField(childViewModel),
        me.getSliderAndVField(childViewModel),
        /* remove this one as it is the alpha field */
        //me.getSliderAndAField(childViewModel),
        me.getPreviewAndButtons(childViewModel, config)
    ];

    me.callParent(arguments);
},
```

Comment: Overriding should work but not ideal, since you may want that in other cases.

If you extend, the parent class will override your configuration when you call callParent().